# How to Allow quick development in Appcelerator Studio?

Tags: titanium, appcelerator

How do I re-enable the below behavior?

I USED to have the below behavior...now I don't. I have to re-compile the whole project for every change which is killing productivity for me.

I cut and pasted the below text from another question as it explains it much better than I can....

**For an iphone simulator build, the .js files are run directly by the simulator without going through the compile step needed for a distribution build. While this saves some time by itself, the real advantage is that the simulator will dynamically use whatever changes you make to a .js file when you navigate to a window using an external .js reference (i.e. the url property). So changes to app.js still need to relaunch the project. But for windows opened later, you can navigate to the window to see how it looks or test code, then just hit the back button in the navigation bar, tweak the .js, and navigate back to the desired window and immediately see the new layout or test the code changes.
This makes tweaking UI layout stuff incredibly fast compared to the android emulator, not to mention code/debug cycles for some *.js logic is as quick as backing up a screen, revising the code, and showing the screen again. Then when you get the logic worked out, switch to android and retest.**

Comment: Please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for future questions. it will help you get better answers.

Comment: Please mark the answer as correct for the one that solved your problem. Please also upvote answers that helped you.

Answer (score 2):

If you have Appcelerator Studio (not Titanium Studio) you can enable LiveView, which attaches a filesystem service to your project and pipes file changes at runtime, bypassing the build process. (aka hotloader, etc)

A) Turn on in Studio

[image: liveview]

B) Use the command line:

`ti build -p ios —-liveview`

Be sure you have the latest updates from Appcelerator to ensure parity with target compilers.

```
$ sudo npm install -g appcelerator
$ appc use latest
$ appc setup
```

If you don't have Appcelerator Studio, you could try third party solutions such as [TiShadow](http://tishadow.yydigital.com/getting%20started):

```
$ sudo npm install -g tishadow
$ ti build -p ios --shadow
$ tishadow server
$ tishadow @ run --shadow
```

Comment: Thanks alot...this is exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

The quickest development feature you can use is LiveView. In Appcelerator Studio, before you run the project you have a little eye icon in the toolbar to enable live view. Then Every change you save to your project will automatically refresh the emulator/device on which you are running.

You can also have a look at a project called [TiShadow](https://github.com/dbankier/TiShadow) which basically does the same and is not related to the Studio.

Comment: Thanks alot...this is exactly what I needed!